# jQuery scrolltop to a div using animate is not working properly in safari

Tags: jquery

I am scrolling top to the section on anchor click. It seems working fine in in all browser but not working properly in safari. in safari it scroll Jerk/direct means pointing to section without scroll.

Below is my code:

```
<div id="example"><ul><li><a href="#scrolltodiv"></li></ul></div>

$('#example ul li a').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var pointosection = $(this).attr('href');
$('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(pointosection).offset().top
            }, 'slow');
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of jQuery you should look at [scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

You can just write: `document.getElementById(pointosection).scrollIntoView()`